# LISP Determine the depth of a list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, depth, clisp

I'm trying to write a function that determines the depth of a list. 
So for

- (1 2 3 4) => 1
- (1 2 3 (4) ) => 2
- (1 2 3 (4 (5))) => 3

and so on.

This is what I've written so far and it works only for linear lists (*depth = 1*) and for lists with *depth = 2*.

I think I'm close to the correct solution but I feel I'm missing something..

```
(defun detlen (lst count)
    (
        cond
            ((null lst) count)
            ((LISTP (car lst)) (setq count (+ count 1)) (detlen (cdr lst) count))
            (t (detlen (cdr lst) count))
    )
)
```

Comment: you may want to attempt to explain your code

Comment: well I was thinking something like this: as I go through the list, if the first element of the list is a list itself I increment the counter and then call detlen on it. If not, i call detlen on the rest of the list

Comment: Does it make sense? AND: your program is doing something else.

Comment: can you elaborate please? on both fronts

Comment: first you need to describe the problem better. What is the depth of a list? Then you need to come up with more and different examples. Maybe ten or more. The examples should include the corner cases. Then come back with an idea how to solve it and try to code it.

Comment: well the depth is the number of nested list ( list in list ) ex: (1 2 3) -> no nested list so depth = 1; (1 (2) 3) -> (2) is a nested list in the main list so depth = 2; (1 2 ( 3 (4))) -> depth is 3 because (4) is a nested list in the list (3 (4)) which is of the depth = 2

Comment: what about the empty list? a list with two sublists? a list with three sublists? one with four?

Comment: well a list with 2 sublists has the depth of 2: (1 2 (3) (4)) has the depth = 2. As far as empty list is concerned I think that a empty list counts: for example (1 2 ()) has depth 2, () has depth 1

Comment: (((1)) (((((2)))))) ?  ( (((3))) ((2)) (1))  ?

Comment: ( ((1)) (((((2))))) ) => depth = 6. ( (((3))) ((2)) (1) ) => 4. An easy way to determine with your eye is to add 1 for each '(' and subtract 1 for each '1' ( kind of dynamic programming ) and the maximum is the depth. For the first example 0 +1 = 1 , 1+1 = 2, 2 + 1 = 3, 3 - 1 = 2, 2 - 1 = 1, 1 + 1 = 2, 2 + 1 = 3, 3 + 1 = 4, 4 + 1 = 5, 5 + 1 = 6, 6  - 1 = 5, 5 - 1 = 4, 4 - 1 = 3, 3 - 1 = 2, 2 - 1 = 1, 1 - 1 = 0

Comment: where is 'maximum' in your code?

Comment: the way is for you to determine and understand more easily, it is not the idea to implement

Comment: you said maximum. But your code does not compute any maximum. Why?

Comment: the comment with maximum was me explaining the problem, and how to easily compute and determine. The idea with the maximum from parenthesis computation is not a viable solution to implement it in LISP

Comment: my idea is to go through a list and for each element to determine it's depth and add 1 to it

Comment: But that does not work on the examples I gave you.

Comment: then i don't know what idea will work

Comment: the idea with the maximum

Comment: ok, i will think about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The depth of a list is:

```
(+ 1 (reduce #'max (mapcar #'depth list) :initial-value 0))
```

Compute all depths and then take the maximum. Add one. A non-list has depth 0.

```
CL-USER 195 > (defun depth (list)
                (if (listp list)
                    (+ 1 (reduce #'max (mapcar #'depth list)
                                 :initial-value 0))
                    0))
DEPTH

CL-USER 196 > (depth '(((2)) (1)))
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about this, and I realised that you can generalise it nicely.  If you have two operations, `along` which moves a cursor along some object`and`down`which moves down into elements of it, as well as an`applicable?`predicate which tells you if`down`can be called, then you can write this rather general function to compute the`down`-depth of something (this is in Racket, where it's easier because of Lisp-1-ness):

```
(define (dual-depth thing down along applicable?)
  ;; given dual operations down and along, and a test, applicable?,
  ;; return the down depth of thing.
  ;; This is zero if applicable? is false, and can fail to terminate if
  ;; the structure has cycles either in down or along.
  (let dd ([it thing])
    (if (applicable? it)
      (let dd-loop ([tail it] [so-far 0])
        (if (not (applicable? tail))
            so-far
            (dd-loop (along tail) (max so-far (+ 1 (dd (down tail)))))))
      0)))
```

And then

```
(define car-depth
  ;; the depth of a cons tree thought of the way it is written
  (λ (l) (dual-depth l car cdr cons?)))

(define cdr-depth
  ;; the depth of a cons tree thought of the other way
  (λ (l) (dual-depth l cdr car cons?)))
```

Or even:

```
(define car-depth
  (curryr dual-depth car cdr cons?))

(define cdr-depth
  (curryr dual-depth cdr car cons?))
```